# Scala WartRemover with java.io.Serializable

Tags: scala, scala-wartremover

I just hit a nasty bug where I had, essentially,

```
sealed trait T extends Product with Serializable
case object O extends T
val mistake = List("foo", "bar", O /* forgot O.toString */)
```

So scala went ahead and inferred `List[java.io.Serializable]` for this list, since `String` is not `scala.Serializable`, but is `java.io.Serializable`, and T is `scala.Serializable` which extends `java.io.Serializable`.  I typically rely on WartRemover to catch such mistakes, but in this case it didn't.  Apparently it only complains about inferring `scala.Serializable`.  Is there any reason to not have the wart also warn about `java.io.Serializable`?

Comment: Open a bug report at their git page?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable addition... in the meantime, you can [create your own Wart](http://www.wartremover.org/doc/adding-your-own-warts.html), of course

Comment: Made a PR for this: https://github.com/wartremover/wartremover/pull/380